# How to depend on different subtask based on dynamic condition, in sbt

Tags: sbt

I have a dependent task for `publish` and `publishLocal`, which I'd like to act slightly differently on the two (e.g. not allowing actual publish of snapshot versions).

Is there a way in `sbt` API that I could sniff the topmost task, from within the dependency?

I tried this:

```
def pick: TaskKey[Unit] = {
  if (isSnapshot.value) {
    aTask
  } else {
    bTask  // the one `publish` is dependent on
  }
}
```

That would pick the right dependency for `publishLocal`, but sbt doesn't allow this:

```
/Users/akauppi/Git/boots-akka-http/stups.sbt:140: error: `value` can only be used within a task or setting macro, such as :=, +=, ++=, Def.task, or Def.setting.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a dynamic task (a `Def.Initialize[Task[T]]`). Try this:

```scala
def pick: Def.Initialize[Task[Unit]] = Def.taskDyn {
  if (isSnapshot.value) {
    aTask
  } else {
    bTask
  } 
}
```

You can can directly initialize a `Task[T]` with a `Def.Initialize[Task[T]]`:

```
lazy val pickTask = Def.taskKey[Unit]("Run the picked task.")

pickTask := pick
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I did not need to use the `pickTask` at all, but placed `pick` as the dependency of the upper task. This is probably okay, since I don't need to run `pick` by itself explicitly, ever.

Comment: Yes, you don't ever need a `Setting` for anything that you're not planning on referencing via the console or changing in a build file.